# Event listener that removed the element didn't work without being redeclared (basically copied) on list items after list update and reset. Why?

Tags: javascript, list, event-listener

My homework was about building a page with a list that had to be manipulated in JavaScript only: items added, deleted, updated, checked/unchecked with some very little CSS help.

The code had two problems.
First, when I added something to the list, I wasn't able to delete it afterwards, only toggle it.
Not only I wasn't able to delete the added item, I wasn't able to delete any other item. Maybe because, to avoid reduplication, I erased the original array and list and created them again using the generating function (the one that took elements from the array and structured them into a list, 'addtoList()')?

I tried to add items separately, not altogether, but then I still wasn't able to delete the added ones, only the ones that were in the list from the beginning.

The problem was sorted when I reassigned, basically copied, inside the 'updateList()' the '.close' event-listener of the <span> element. I put it right after the recreation of the list from the updated array. I was just experimenting, playing around, and it worked.

Why is it working now and not before? I thought the event listener was attached to the <span> inside the 'addtoList()' so I didn't have to redo this. It worked when the list was created for the first time inside 'manipulateList()'. I really can't grasp the problem and also its solution.

Second, when I deleted something from the initial array/list, the chosen item dissapeared correctly from the list but not from the array. It was always the last element of the array (maybe its index wasn't updated correctly, I don't know), not the one selected.

Until I made it 'let item = li.innerText.slice(0, -1);' instead of 'let item = li.innerText;' (though that made some other requirements redundant, I explain more in the code's comments), the thing didn't work properly.
Why now and not before? Again I feel I am out of my depth. Got the result empirically but I feel that's not enough.

Your help will be much appreciated.
Thanks!

```
let groceryList = ["bread", "butter", "milk", "cheese", "chocolate"];

let list = document.querySelector("#itemList");

/*  Function to add items to the Shopping List. */

function addtoList() {
groceryList.forEach((item) => {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = item;
    list.appendChild(li);
    let span = document.createElement("span");
    li.append(span);
    span.classList.add("close");
    span.innerText = "\u00D7";
    li.addEventListener("click", checkedToggle, false);
});
}

function checkedToggle() {
this.classList.toggle("checked_style");
}

/*  Function that displays each item in the Grocery List array as list elements in the <ul> tag, 
then removes one item from the list. */

manipulateList = () => {
addtoList();
console.log(groceryList);
setTimeout(() => {
    removefromListandArray("bread");
}, "2000");
};
manipulateList();

/*  Function that updates the 'groceryList' by getting the value from the <input>. */

function updateList() {
let inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
if (inputValue == "") {
    alert("Please enter a shopping item.");
    return false;
} else {
    groceryList.push(inputValue);
    console.log(groceryList);
            document.querySelector("#input").value = "";

/*  Resetting the Shopping List to prevent reduplication before update. A neat looking list with 5 items
```

should be displayed, not a 9 items long list that adds 5 items (of which just the last one is new,
the one that came through input) to the previous 4 items long list. */

```
    document.querySelector("#itemList").innerHTML = "";

    addtoList();

/*  The event listener on the <span> didn't work without being copied (thus redeclared and redefined)  
here. For none of the list items, old or newly added. I have to read more about this problem to be able
 to grasp it but, for now, this tweak at least makes 'updateList()' work properly. */

    document.querySelectorAll(".close").forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener("click", deleteandNone);
    });
}
}

/*  Function to delete an item from both the Grocery List array and the Shopping List display. */

function removefromListandArray(item) {
let tbRmvdIndx = groceryList.indexOf(item);
list.removeChild(list.children[tbRmvdIndx]);
groceryList.splice(tbRmvdIndx, 1);
console.log(groceryList);
}

/*  Function to delete an item from the Grocery List array only. */

function removefromArrayOnly(item) {
let tbRmvdIndx = groceryList.indexOf(item);
groceryList.splice(tbRmvdIndx, 1);
console.log(groceryList);
}

/*  Adding a click event listener to each <span class="close">. When the event is triggered, deletes the
  item from the Grocery List and sets the display style to none for the specific list parent element. */

/*  Without the '.slice(0, -1)'(that actually makes the '.display = "none"' redundant, at least for my
    current understanding), and, as a consequence, the 'removefromArrayOnly()' 
    redundant as well (could have used 'removefromListandArray()' instead), the 'deleteandNone()' 
    just didn't work. The deletion worked well on the list, but not on the chosen element as regards
    the array, always erasing the last element of the 'groceryList'. */

    /* The previous code that seemed to work but didn't work well was: 

        const deleteandNone = function () {
            let li = event.target.parentNode;
            let item = li.innerText;
            removefromArrayOnly(item);
            li.style.display = "none"; 
        };     */


const deleteandNone = function () {
let li = event.target.parentNode;
let item = li.innerText.slice(0, -1);
removefromArrayOnly(item);
li.style.display = "none";
};
document.querySelectorAll(".close").forEach((item) => {
item.addEventListener("click", deleteandNone);
});

/*  Adding a keyup event listener to the HTML element with id="input".  */

let input = document.getElementById("input");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("addBtn").click();
}
});


THE HTML FILE

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Shopping List</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Shopping List</h2>
        <div class="header">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Item">
            <span onclick="updateList()" id="addBtn">Add Item</span>
    </div>
        <ul id="itemList"></ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

THE CSS FILE

* {
  color: purple;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  }

body {
background-color: lightpink;
}

.checked_style {
text-decoration: line-through;
text-decoration-color: blue;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use event delegation - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/event-delegation-javascript

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems a plausible path! I'll explore the subject, redo the task, and let you know of the outcome.

Comment: Don't refactor your code and force to it work with event delegation. Try to build a simple demo first, and if it works for you rebuild your code on top of it. Good luck :)